# How do I install SWIG with WHM or Cpanel?

Tags: centos, vps

I have a VPS with SSH and WHM access. Though I don't really know anything about command-line stuff. Now in order to install a payment API I need to install SWIG on my server, but I have no clue what to do. Any help is appreciated. Please be as descriptive as you can. Also please feel free to ask me any further information you may need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect to your server via SSH and issue the command

```
yum install swig
```

Also, hire someone for this, payment handling isn't a good starting ground for amateurs.